# Function _admin_bar_bump_cb is deprecated since version 6.4.0

Tags: admin-bar

I am getting the following error message since 6.4.0:

> Function _admin_bar_bump_cb is deprecated since version 6.4.0

However I am not using `_admin_bar_bump_cb` in any theme/plugins.

`debug_backtrace()` leads back to the `wp_head()` function so I wonder from where the function/hook is being triggered in the first place?

On top of that I am using the following mechanism to deactivate the admin bar.

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
    
wp_deregister_script('admin-bar');
wp_deregister_style('admin-bar');
```

Consequently, I am perplexed as to why `_admin_bar_bump_cb` is unexpectedly triggered.

Its intended purpose is to append the admin bar style to the document's head, which should remain disabled initially...

Comment: Try adding the WP Debug plugin which allows you to trace things, including determining filters that might be called. It may be a timing issue as to when/if your filter is being run.